# Appending iframe to DOM and making sure contents load before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the following code:

```
  function callIframe(type, cat) {
    var send = false;
    var axel = Math.random() + "";
    var a = axel * 10000000000000;
    var iframe = $('<iframe src="http://domain.com/;src=12345678;type=' + type + ';cat=' + cat + ';ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" ><iframe>');    
    $('body').append(iframe);   
  }
```

and:

```
$("a").click(function(e){  
  var $form = $(this).parent();
  callIframe("signu903", "hptes318");  
  $form.get(0).submit();  
});
```

My issue is the form is submitting before the contents of the iframe are fully loaded.  I know a callback would address this issue but I am then reliant on the iframe loading to submit the form.  I am just looking or best practice in this case.

Note: I do not have any access to the iframe code.

Thanks in advance,

JN

Comment: I think you are contradicting yourself. You want to make sure the form isn't submitted until the iframe is loaded, but you don't want to rely on the iframe loading.

Comment: @KevinB I am looking to have a fail safe way of submitting the form even if the iframe does not load.  The application is not dependent on the iframe for running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `setTimeout` so that it will wait x seconds for the iframe to load, and if it doesn't load in the allotted amount of time, it submits anyway.

try this function:

```
function callIframe(type, cat) {
    var send = false;
    var axel = Math.random() + "";
    var a = axel * 10000000000000;
    var iframe = $('<iframe src="http://domain.com/;src=12345678;type=' + type + ';cat=' + cat + ';ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" ><iframe>');
    $('body').append(iframe);
    return iframe;
}​
```

and then this code

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this).parent();
    var iframe = callIframe("signu903", "hptes318");
    iframe.load($form.get(0).submit);
    setTimeout($form.get(0).submit,5000);
});​
```

If the iframe takes longer than 5 seconds to load, the form submits anyway.

you may need to add more logic to prevent the submit from happening twice.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin B. This is exactly the sort of solution I was looking / thinking of.  This seems like it will insure the form is submitted in any case.